# Javascript Multiple Alert Boxes

Tags: javascript

I created a little register form in HTML.

And I created a JS that pops up an alert for each of them if any of them are left blank

Now I want to combine all the alerts into a single one for example at the start a box will appear with all alerts and if you complete one if you push submit the next box will appear without the alert of the box you already completed

This is my JS Code:

```js
function validate()
      {

         if( document.inrValid.Nume.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Introduceti va rog numele!" );
            document.inrValid.Nume.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

if( document.inrValid.Prenume.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Introduceti va rog Prenumele!" );
            document.inrValid.Prenume.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

         if( document.inrValid.EMail.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Introduceti va rog Emailul!" );
            document.inrValid.EMail.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

         if( document.inrValid.Telefon.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Introduceti va rog Numarul de Telefon!" );
            document.inrValid.Telefon.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

if( document.inrValid.parola.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Introduceti va rog Parola!" );
            document.inrValid.parola.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

         return( true );
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" name="inrValid" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <p>Nume <input type="text" name="Nume" /></p>
              <p>Prenume <input type="text" name="Prenume" /></p>
              <p>EMail <input type="text" name="EMail" /></p>
              <p>Telefon <input type="number" name="Telefon" /></p>
              <p>Parola <input type="password" name="parola" /></p>
               <p><input type="submit" onclick="clickAlert()" value="Submit" name="clickAlert" /></p>
      </form>
      <script src="script.js">  </script>
   </body>
</html
```

Comment: I recommend you to use the `required` attribute, so you don't need to write your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, you could use the `required` attribute as a small form of validation.

You could also add all of your error messages to an array, for example:

```js
var checkForm = function () {
  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
  var errors = [];
  
  if (foo.value.length === 0) {
    errors.push('Foo is blank');
  }
  
  if (bar.value.length === 0) {
    errors.push('Bar is blank');
  }
  
  alert(errors.join(','));
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="checkForm()">
  <input id="foo" type="text" />
  <input id="bar" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```